# How to reduce image size in C#?

Tags: c#

I was using `Graphics.DrawImage(DrawText())` to DrawText into Image.

The problem is: I only draw three text but origin images size is: 226kb and output image when Save() ~3.45mb. It too larger.

Image dimensions: `2732 * 3200`.

I only loop my list `textFileSplit`, and this list only has three items.

This is all my code to save image:

```
foreach (string text in lstTextFromFile)
{
    count++;
    if (text == "") continue;
    Graphics gra = Graphics.FromImage(img);
    string st = lstImgAdded.Items[k].Text;
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(@"" + st);
    bmp = (Bitmap)ResizePanel(bmp, panel2);
    panel2.BackgroundImage = bmp;
    Graphics gbmp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    string[] textFileSplit = text.Split('-');
    for (int u = 0; u < textFileSplit.Count(); u++)
    {
        myColorLabel = activeLabels[u+1].ForeColor;
        gbmp.DrawImage(
        DrawText(textFileSplit[u], fontType, myColorLabel,
            Color.Transparent),
        Point.Round(StretchImageSize(new Point(activeLabels[u+1].Location.X, activeLabels[u+1].Location.Y), panel2)));
    }
    gra.Dispose();
    Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();
    ScaleImage(bmp, witdhImg, heightImg)
        .Save(linkLocation + "\\" + id + "." + imgType,
            ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

In class `ScaleImage()` I tried to keep dimensions like origin images:

```
public Image ScaleImage(Image image, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
{
    var ratioX = (double)maxWidth / image.Width;
    var ratioY = (double)maxHeight / image.Height;
    var ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);
    var ratio2 = Math.Max(ratioX, ratioY);

    var newWidth = (int)(image.Width * ratio);
    var newHeight = (int)(image.Height * ratio2);

    var newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
    Graphics.FromImage(newImage).DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
    return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to set the resolution and quality in your scaling function:

```
    public Image ScaleImage(Image image, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
    {
        var ratioX = (double)maxWidth / image.Width;
        var ratioY = (double)maxHeight / image.Height;
        var ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);
        var ratio2 = Math.Max(ratioX, ratioY);

        var newWidth = (int)(image.Width * ratio);
        var newHeight = (int)(image.Height * ratio2);

        var newImage = var newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, image.PixelFormat);
        newImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

        Graphics grPhoto = Graphics.FromImage(newImage);
        grPhoto.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;

        grPhoto.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);

        grPhoto.Dispose();
        return newImage;           
    }
```

Apply EncoderParameters with low Quality:

```
   ImageCodecInfo pngEncoder = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders().Where(k=> k.FormatID == ImageFormat.Png.Guid).First();
   EncoderParameters encoderParameters;
   encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
   encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality,  60L);
   ScaleImage(bmp, witdhImg, heightImg)
    .Save(linkLocation + "\\" + id + "." + imgType, pngEncoder ,encoderParameters);
```

Comment: I checked with `High mode`. There is no difference between `Hight` vs `HighQualityBicubic`.

Comment: One last thing, try passing EncoderParameters with low quality to Save() method, answer updated.

Comment: That's working. But before, I save with Image.Png it keeps transparent. I updated with your code and background change to black.

Comment: Thank you very much @ShadiShaaban. I change to info[4] to set `image/Png`. That's working.

Comment: Excellent, I've also updated the answer to use PNG Encoder instead.

Comment: Seem choose png will increase the size of the image. I checked again and saw this picture also keep 3.xMB.
If a change to JPEG Encoder, background image change to Color.Black.

Have you any idea?

Comment: I would suggest to use the original image pixel format as follows: var newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, image.PixelFormat); // answer updated.

Comment: This is applies to jpeg image type.

Comment: Could you provide a direct link for the image you're working on? I was able to successfully shrink down a 5mb transparent PNG to 50kb using the above code.

Comment: You can download at here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_2h5DVOY2ouWHBlTW5lTEdLams

Include original image with ~200Mb and image I exported about ~3.4Mb